# Acknowledging Someone in a Research Paper

Tags: paper-submission, acknowledgement

We finished preparing a manuscript and there is a researcher who helped and advised us on many aspects of the research. I know this may sound trivial but I would like to ask if it is required from me to ask him if I can mention him in the acknowledgment or not. Can I mention him without taking his permission to do so? Thank you in advance...